# Declaración de variables de Python

Tags: python

Necesito saber cómo declarar una variable para luego usarla en una función que me permita contar la cantidad de una letra en específico dentro de un texto, necesito que me devuelva una respuesta como:

> Hay 32 "A" dentro del texto.

Comment: Bienvenida a [es.so] nathaly, para poder ayudarte de acuerdo a las [normas de este sitio](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) es necesario que aportes el código o al menos expliques lo que has intentado hasta el momento. Te recomiendo que te mires [Cómo preguntar](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) . Para contar las ocurrencias de una letra en una cadena puedes hacer uso del método [count()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.count) de las cadenas. Saludos.